# Problem trying to code a mathematical test which returns certain numbers

Tags: java, loops

My issue seems simple, but I'm relatively new to programming and I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code.

I am supposed to return the number of numbers under n (max 1000000) that have both a 7 and a 9 in them. For example, n=10 returns 0, n=100 returns 2 (from 79 and 97) etc.

```
int allWith7Or9(int n) 
{
  int count = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if(i%10==7 || i%100==7 || i%1000==7 || i%10000==7 || i%100000==7 || i%1000000==7)
    {
      if(i%10==9 || i%100==9 || i%1000==9 || i%10000==9 || i%100000==9 || i%1000000==9)
      {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

I realize that I could have used &&, and I tried to, but my code keeps coming up with 0, and I have no idea why. I implemented this at least 3 different ways.

Here is another implementations I tried:

```
int allWith7Or9(int n) 
{
  int count = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if((i%10==7 || i%100==7 || i%1000==7 || i%10000==7 || i%100000==7
    || i%1000000==7) && (i%10==9 || i%100==9 || i%1000==9
    || i%10000==9 || i%100000==9 || i%1000000==9))
    {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `if (cond1) { if (cond2) { ... } }` is basically `if (cond1 && cond2) { ... }` - and if both conditions cannot be true, that's always false.

Comment: But both conditions MUST be true! Take 100. Looping with both conditions says that ANY of the numbers prior must have both a 7 and a 9, correct? So we have i.e. 79 and 97. However, it returns 0, not 2. How so?

Comment: Why not use `String current = String.valueOf(i);` and the condition `if (current.contains("7") && current.contains("9"))` to simplify the logic and make it readable?

Comment: Mm I am not allowed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(i%10==7 || i%100==7 || i%1000==7 || i%10000==7 || i%100000==7 || i%1000000==7)
{
  if(i%10==9 || i%100==9 || i%1000==9 || i%10000==9 || i%100000==9 || i%1000000==9)
  {
    count++;
  }
}
```

is basically

```
if(cond1)
{
  if(cond2)
  {
    count++;
  }
}
```

which is basically:

```
if(cond1 && cond2)
{
  count++;
}
```

since both conditions must be true to increment `count`.

And those conditions aren't true at the same time because

```
i % 100 == 7
```

isn't what you probably mean. This isn't checking for numbers like 70, 71 etc, it's checking for numbers what have a remainder 7 when divided by 100, like 7, 107, 207. So

```
i%10==7 || i%100==7 || i%1000==7 || i%10000==7 || i%100000==7 || i%1000000==7
```

is only matched when `i == 7`, and

```
i%10==9 || i%100==9 || i%1000==9 || i%10000==9 || i%100000==9 || i%1000000==9
```

is only matched when `i == 9`. `7 != 9`, so the counter won't be incremented.

---

You can rewrite the conditions as:

```
i%10==7 || (i/10)%10==7 || (i/100)%10==7 etc
```

But writing it all out like this is messy and error-prone.

Instead, use a loop:

```
boolean found7 = false;
boolean found9 = false;
for (int ii = i; ii > 0: ii /= 10)  {
  switch (ii % 10) {
    case 7: found7 = true; break;
    case 9: found9 = true; break;
  }
}

if (found7 && found9) {
  count++;
}
```

This uses two flags to indicate which of the digits you have found. Check the last digit to see if it is 7 or 9, then divide by 10 to discard that digit and move on to the next.

Comment: A few things. One, in line 3, did you mean int ii = 1;? Secondly, I am still running all 0's. I believe that your code is checking if the same digit is both 7 and 9, hmm.

Comment: One: no. Two: I don't know what "I am still running all 0's" means. You believe wrongly. [Demo](https://ideone.com/j0ryCu)

Comment: Ahh I see my mistake. Thank you immensely.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first condition is wrong. For example 79.
Condition for 7 does not works 79%10 = 9, 79%100 = 79. Seven is not detected.
It should be something like iterate through all digits of number. So check for one number can be like this.

```
boolean have7and9(int a) {
  boolean seven = false, nine = false;  
  while(a > 0) {
    if (a%10 == 7) seven = true;
    if (a%10 == 9) nine = true;
    a /= 10;
  }
  return seven && nine;
}
```

Comment: This is checking only the same digit... Running all 0's.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that your conditions are wrong.

For example, `i % 100 == 7` does not test if the "tens" digit of `i` is `7`.  It *actually* tests if the last two digits are `07`.  Do the math ....

To test the "tens" digit is `7` in a single expression, you need to use something like

```
(i / 10) % 10 == 7
```

(You should be able to work out a correct solution from the above.  And there are at least two different approaches that you could take.)